# Convergence of sequence of real powers

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\ 0<a_n→0 $ and $\ b_n→b>0 $. Prove $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n^{b_n}=0 $.

This is what I'd like to do  but I'm not sure how to continue.

Let $\ \epsilon>0 $ we know that there exists N s.t. for every $\ n>N$ $\ |a_n|<\epsilon$ and $\ |b_n-b|< \epsilon$.

From this we gather $\ (-\epsilon)^{b-\epsilon}<a_n^{b_n}<(\epsilon)^{b+\epsilon}$.

I'd like to define $\ \epsilon$ as a series $\epsilon _k >0$ s.t. $\lim_{n \to \infty}\epsilon_k=0$.

I am unsure how to proceed from here.

Would it be sufficient to say:

$\ 0<a_n^{b_n}<(\epsilon_k)^{b+\epsilon_k}$.

Using limit arithmetic we know that $\ {b+\epsilon_k}→b $ and$\ \epsilon_k→0$

So $\ (\epsilon_k)^{b+\epsilon_k}→0$ and using the squeeze theorem we know that $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n^{b_n}=0 $.

Does that suffice?

Comment: First of all, $a_n>0$, so the lower bound for $a_n^{b_n}$ is just $0$ (good since $(-\epsilon)^{b-\epsilon}$ is probably not defined). Second, when $\epsilon<1$, bigger powers of $\epsilon$ are smaller, so the upper bound for $a_n^{b_n}$ should be $\epsilon^{b-\epsilon}$ rather than $\epsilon^{b+\epsilon}$.

Comment: That being said, you could set $\epsilon=\frac1k$ and learn that when $n$ is sufficiently large, $a_n^{b_n} < (\frac1k)^{b-\frac1k}$, which itself is less than $(\frac1k)^{b/2}$ when $k$ is sufficiently large; and this upper bound certainly tends to $0$.

Comment: A different approach from the start: to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n^{b_n}=0$, it is equivalent to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n\log a_n = -\infty$; and this isn't difficult given your assumptions.

Comment: The only thing I don't understand is on what basis can I change the upper bound to $\ \epsilon^{b-\epsilon}$, as what I originally wrote is based on the given limits.

Comment: Third line: You have $a_n,b_n$ mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little different from your approach: There exists $N$ such that $0<a_n <1, b_n> b/2$ for $n\ge N.$ For such $n,$ we have

$$\tag 10< a_n^{b_n} < a_n ^{b/2}.$$

(A higher power of a number in $(0,1)$ gives us something smaller.) The function $f(x) = x^{b/2}$ is continuous on $[0,\infty).$ Note that the right side of $(1)$ is $f(a_n).$ Since $a_n \to 0,$ the right side of $(1)$ approaches $f(0)  =0.$ We're done by the squeeze theorem.